# Does 19th century Canadian Presbyterian teaching prohibit wearing flowers to church?

Tags: church-history, presbyterianism, canada

Cross-posted from [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/was-it-inappropriate-in-19th-century-canada-to-wear-flowers-in-a-hat-to-church), since comments there indicate this might be the more appropriate SE.

In the novel *[Anne of Green Gables](https://gutenberg.org/files/64365/64365-h/64365-h.htm)*, Anne wears a hat with flowers in it to church, and is criticized by her neighbour and adoptive parents for it:

> It was not until the next Friday that Marilla heard the story of the flower-wreathed hat. She came home from Mrs. Lynde’s and called Anne to account.
>
> “Anne, Mrs. Rachel says you went to church last Sunday with your hat rigged out ridiculous with roses and buttercups. What on earth put you up to such a caper? A pretty-looking object you must have been!”
>
> “Oh, I know pink and yellow aren’t becoming to me,” began Anne.
>
> “Becoming fiddlesticks! It was putting flowers on your hat at all, no matter what colour they were, that was ridiculous. You are the most aggravating child!”

This is weird to me, since I can easily imagine someone doing this in the modern world without getting much comment, in fact there are vendors selling exactly [these kind of hats](https://www.etsy.com/market/floral_church_hats).

Was it inappropriate to wear flowers in a hat to church in 19th century Canada? The comments in the History SE question indicate that this could be something to do with the author's denomination, which is Presbyterian.

Comment: Anne refers to being struck by the words of the nineteenth paraphrase: "Quick as the slaughtered squadrons fell In Midian’s evil day". These words do occur in Paraphrase 19 of the Church of Scotland, which is Presbyterian. This seems to confirm that Anne was attending a Presbyterian church, modelled on the C of S.. https://www.bible.com/bible/3051/ISA.9.MP1781

Comment: Neither the minister nor the Sunday School teacher expressed any concern, and nobody sems to have complained that Anne's hat was immoral. It was just mentioned in passing the following Friday to Marilla. There is no suggestion by anybody in the book that it was morally or religiously inappropriate. It is simply that she looked ridiculous, since different from other girls.